# Why Linking.openURL fires automaticaly without TouchableOpacity?

Tags: javascript, react-native, function, touchableopacity

i have a problem with function in React Native.
I checking if the String is e-mail, text or phone and returns appropriate object, e.g Linking.openURL(`mailto:${phone}`).

But function automatically fires the URL and forwarding me to Phone Application, what im doing wrong?

A function to check value in a String

```
function checkResult(result){
  let emailChecker = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if( !( emailChecker.test(result))){
    return Linking.openURL(`mailto:${result}`)
  }

  if(isNaN(result)){
    return Linking.openURL(`tel:${result}`)
  }
}
```

My touchableOpacity

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={checkResult(result)}
        >
        <Text
          style={{
            color: 'blue',
            fontSize: 20,
            marginTop: 10,
            marginBottom: 40,
          }}
        >
          {result}
        </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onPress={checkResult(result)}` this will result in calling the function `checkResult` when you pass it to the component, so the function will execute on render.

Update your onPress callback to `() => checkResult(result)`.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => checkResult(result)} 
>
  <Text
      style={{
      color: 'blue',
      fontSize: 20,
      marginTop: 10,
      marginBottom: 40,
    }}
    >
      {result}
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

for more details on passing function to component - [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer, i have to add one more {} to onPress - onPress={() => {checkResult(result)}}

Comment: That is required in case of having multiple lines or functions to execute, like 
 onPress={() => { 
   checkResult(result);
   // lines of code to execute
 }}